# wordpress custom post type taxonomy permalink

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy

I have created a new custom post type and a new custom taxonomy for a my site.

I created a custom "rewrite" post type and taxonomy using this code:

However it's working like this (https://Site-url/sub-site-name/conditions/ankle-fracture/).

But i need add condition-type also like bellow the url:

https://Site-url/sub-site-name/conditions/**ankle**/ankle-fracture/

```
function custom_conditions_permalink( $wp_rewrite ) {

  $rules = array();
  $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'name' => 'conditions', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );
  $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( 'name' => 'condition-type', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );

  foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    $post_type_name = $post_type->name; // 'conditions'
    $post_type_slug = $post_type->rewrite['slug']; // 'conditions'


    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
      if ( $taxonomy->object_type[0] == $post_type_name ) {

        $terms = get_categories( array( 'type' => $post_type_name, 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            print_r($term);
          $rules[$post_type_slug . '/' . $term->slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?' . $term->taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug;

        }
      }
    }
  }
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_conditions_permalink');
```

How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like conditions/condition-type/post-type-name/?

I am a bit stuck on this and I would be grateful if you could help me with this.

Thanks!